# What is the word for a small (under 50 bp) structural variant?

Tags: genetics, terminology, genomes

What is the word for a small (under 50 bp) SV? Perhaps it is MNV (multi-nucleotide variant)? Something like microindel? I do not like SNV as "single nucleotide" is not really correct and I want a indel-specific term.

SV = structural variant

bp = base pairs

SNV = single nucleotide variant

indel = insertion or deletion

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Yes, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can clearly find instances of "[microindel](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20144947/)" in the literature. However it does not seem to be very common.

"Small indel" appears to be the preferred term, noted [here](https://bmcmedgenomics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12920-020-00818-6):

> Typically, small indels are termed for insertions/deletions of shorter than 50 bps while longer ones are considered as structural variants (SVs) [2, 3].

For example, [DeepVariant](https://www.nature.com/articles/nbt.4235) uses this term.